# bootstrap cards spilling over rows and affecting margins of other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive

*NB I'm new to programming and this is my first post so please excuse any misleading code or confused terminology etc.*

I'm playing around with bootstrap cards on a blog template and I'm trying to separate two rows so that the height of an element in the first row doesn't affect the position of an element in the second row.

Here is a link to the project: https://codepen.io/jreecebowman/pen/NyOKpV

Beneath the main navbar, there is one `.row` with two cards inside it, in two separate columns: `col-md-8` & `col-md-4`.

The `.row` beneath this is affected by the `.row` above i.e. the margin between the two `col-md-8` cards on either row. If you compare this with the row below, there is no margin; the cards are stacked on top of each other. This is how I would like the first row, regardless of the height of the smaller card on the right.

I can put the cards on the left into `.card-columns`, but that doesn't really solve my problem because I can only make it half the screen width using an `@media` enquiry in the css.

I hope this is clear enough. Could anybody help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the left cards in 1 column `col-md-8`...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wotw col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/7CH0uHS9IT

The reason you have a spacing/margin in the first row is because flexbox (Bootstrap 4) is used which makes all columns in a row the same height. Since the right card inside `col-md-4` is taller, it's making the whole row taller.

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup so that the div spreading over 4 columns `col-md-4` is separated out from the div spreading over 8 columns `col-md-8`